Как подписаться на результат запроса к DB Room Kotlin Android?
помогите пожалуйста получить ответ от базы данных Room, стартовал с этой инструкции
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room?hl=ru,
запрашиваю простейшее - список строк только что созданной базы данных, использую рекомендуемую корутину Flow (без неё приложение падает), ответом приходит объект kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SafeFlow@...., вероятно нужно подписаться на ответ чтобы получить List? Пожалуйста, ответьте исправлением моего кода, чтобы Log вывел ответ, иначе я не пойму куда и как его пристроить. ) Я честно рыл stackoverflow пару дней, но не нашел пример кода.
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import androidx.room.Query
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow

@Entity(tableName = "users")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long = 0,
    val name: String,
    val age: Int
)

@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM users")
    fun getAllUsers(): Flow<List<User>>
}

@Database(entities = [User::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        lateinit var database: AppDatabase
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }

        database = Room.databaseBuilder(this, AppDatabase::class.java, "my_database")
            .build()

        val allUsers = database.userDao().getAllUsers()
        Log.d("RoomDB", allUsers.toString())
    }
}


Если вам не нужен flow, то и не нужно его указывать. Возвращайте просто List<User>, а если нужны корутины, то добавьте suspend

Без Flow приложение падает с ошибкой "Возможно слишком долгое ожидание". На suspend я не знаю как передать задание с основного потока. Был бы признателен за возможное решение в виде исправленного моего кода, сразу протестирую.

lifecycleScope.launch{ allUsers.collect{  Log.d("RoomDB", it.toString()) } } извините, если что-то криво, пишу по памяти.

вообще, рекомендую изучить корутины, прежде чем переходить к БД, работой с API и прочими асинхронными вещами. корутины - база, которую нужно знать прежде чем щупать библиотеки.

Спасибо за совет, обязательно изучу, но мне легче заходит новое на рабочих примерах. )
Куда именно попробовать пристроить Ваш код в мой в вопросе? Попробовал в onCreate, редактор всё светит красным, не находит связей.

вместо Log.d("RoomDB", allUsers.toString()) вставьте мой код.

Круть, работает! Оформляйте коротко, я отмечу принятым. Спасибо!

Разобрался с корутинами. ) Создал экземпляр базы в .allowMainThreadQueries() и забрал результат запроса в .apply{this). Но Ваш вариант с подпиской тоже пригодится, спасибо.

.allowMainThreadQueries() это не корутины. это вы разрешили обращаться к БД из главного потока (что не есть хорошо)

Да, нашел это ночью, а к утру понял что это подавление.
Будьте добры еще вот что по Вашему решению, lifecycleScope.launch получается подписка колбэк, и, как я понял, пока не выполнит вложенное задание, плюётся выполнением инструкции не один раз, а может несколько, если таблица запрашивается на изменение другими заданиями. Возможно это как-то изменить (подавить), т.е. заставить сделать только то что от нее ожидается - разовый запрос и разовый возврат результата с таблицы? Или может быть другое решение? Я пока вынужден обращаться с основного потока, но это не гуд.

Я сейчас в DAO заменил Flow на suspend, и вызвал
lifecycleScope.launch{ getAllmsgs().apply{ Log.d("RoomDB", this.toString()) } }, получил разовый ответ. Всё правильно сделал?
